# javascript submitting form does not send data

Tags: javascript

On clicking a button I would like to send data to the server. Submitting the form works, but there are no data send to the server. Only the page is reloaded.

```
            $('#erase').on('click', function() {
                var Myform = document.createElement("form");
                Myform.setAttribute("method", "POST");
                Myform.setAttribute("action", "formular-test.php");

                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "peter");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "hans");

                Myform.appendChild(hiddenField);

                document.body.appendChild(Myform);
                Myform.submit();
                });
```

Any idea?

Comment: u better print item in console to see what happen

Comment: Did you check your network tab? And check the request call formation.

Answer (score 0):

on formular-test.php

try to write `var_dump($_REQUEST);die();`
on first line of php

You'll see this result after that check out your PHP logic.

> { ["peter"]=> string(4) "hans" }

Comment: Thanks for your support. Meanwhile I found a totally different solution. I created a form and click it with Javascript. The form then sends data.